# Firefox extension development: load event only once

Tags: events, firefox, plugins, load

I'm developing a kind of kiosk system for firefox. Therefore I need to listen to the load event, everytime a link is clicked and a new page / document is loaded. I used this in the js file to accomplish that:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    gBrowser.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        alert("load");
    }, false);
}, false);
```

But the event is only fired if i open the new browser window but not on reload or loading another content.
What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [nsIWindowWatcher](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowWatcher) service to do this:

```
let {Services} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});

function windowObserver(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
  if (aTopic == "domwindowopened") {
    let win = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);

    // Do stuff here
  }
}

// To start watching windows do this
Services.ww.registerNotification(windowObserver);

// To stop watching windows do this
Services.ww.unregisterNotification(windowObserver);
```

Comment: I will refer to this later, seems to be a good resource. I solved it with the page-mod API and use the option: contentScriptWhen : "ready"